# Add action to enter in ember textarea input helper

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have used addon ember-autoresize for my textarea to resize my textarea.

```
{{textarea type="text" placeholder="Comment" value=comment_text autofocus="autofocus" rows=1 max-rows=4 autoresize=true 
      enter="commentSave"}}
```

I want to trigger the action when user press enter.But it moves to next line when I press enter.How do I call the action when enter key is pressed in  textarea.

Comment: Why not just use `input` if you don't need multiple lines of text?

Comment: @DanielKmak I need multiple lines of text that why

Answer (score 3):

Create component called `custom-textarea`.

in `components/custom-textarea.js`:

```
export default Ember.TextArea.extend({
  didRender() {
    this.$().keypress(function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

In template, use `custom-textarea` instead of `textarea`:

```
{{custom-textarea type="text" placeholder="Comment" value=comment_text autofocus="autofocus" rows=1 max-rows=4 autoresize=true 
      enter="commentSave"}}
```

See [WORKING DEMO](https://ember-twiddle.com/bb2d3cfb67667d361ff7?openFiles=custom-textarea.component.js%2Ccustom-textarea.template.hbs).

*Approach to prevent default behavior taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5482853/2166409).*

Comment: You can also declare a keypress property. ``keypress(event){ ... }``