# Disable enter in input box

Tags: html, css

I have a `textarea` where it should not be possible to input line breaks by pressing `enter`. How can I disable `enter` in my textarea?

That is the code:

```
<textarea name="textarea" style="width:250px;height:150px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If the user is not allowed to add new lines, then just use an `<input>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disable enter key on specific textboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482825/disable-enter-key-on-specific-textboxes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable New Line in Textarea when Pressed ENTER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779322/disable-new-line-in-textarea-when-pressed-enter)

Comment: @str can I also enlarge the input?

Comment: @BamSam Yes, you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use event.preventdefault and next do what you like. For example

```
<script>
$("textarea").click(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: The *enter* key is not the only way to produce a line feed ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget to use the **keydown** event instead of the click event

```
   $("input").keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery in your web application you can do fallowing trick to disable enter key.

```
$('textarea').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) { return false; }
});
```

else you can use this

```
document.getElementById('textarea_id').addEventListener('keydown', function(k){
    if(k.keyCode == 13) return false;
});
```

I hope this will help you!